# How to get Role of users that have admin role in RoleBaseStrategy plugin as Groovy in Jenkinsfile?

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have used RoleBaseStrategy plugin.
I have this block code in my Jenkinsfile :

```
def authStrategy = Jenkins.instance.getAuthorizationStrategy()
permissions = authStrategy.roleMaps.inject([:]){map, it -> map + it.value.grantedRoles}
Roles = permissions.findAll{ it.value.contains(RUNNER_USER) }.collect{it.key.name}

  if("admin" in Roles) {
    timeout(time: TIMEOUT, unit: 'SECONDS') {
      input(message: "Do you want to overwrite the lock?", ok: "Yes")
    }
  println "job finished"
```

at the end I got my Role list but for [authstrategy](/questions/tagged/authstrategy) Function I got this error and

> Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy

and it doesn't let my pipeline work properly.
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the groovy logic to an external function.

```
def getRoles() {
   def authStrategy = Jenkins.instance.getAuthorizationStrategy()
   permissions = authStrategy.roleMaps.inject([:]){map, it -> map + it.value.grantedRoles}

   return permissions.findAll{ it.value.contains(RUNNER_USER) }.collect{it.key.name}

}
```

In pipeline

```
if("admin" in getRoles()) {
    timeout(time: TIMEOUT, unit: 'SECONDS') {
      input(message: "Do you want to overwrite the lock?", ok: "Yes")
}
```

Complete Pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Run Tests") {
            steps {
                script {
                    def RUNNER_USER = 'admin'
                    def TIMEOUT = 30
                    
                      if("admin" in getRoles(RUNNER_USER)) {
                        timeout(time: TIMEOUT, unit: 'SECONDS') {
                          input(message: "Do you want to overwrite the lock?", ok: "Yes")
                        }
                      }
                      println "job finished"
                        
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}

def getRoles(RUNNER_USER){
    def authStrategy = Jenkins.instance.getAuthorizationStrategy()
    def permissions = authStrategy.roleMaps.inject([:]){map, it2 -> map + it2.value.grantedRoles}
    def Roles = permissions.findAll{ it.value.contains(RUNNER_USER) }.collect{it.key.name}
    return Roles
    
}
```

Comment: I tried this block of code but the result is the same.
Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @AmirTaghia check the updated full Pipeline. It works fine for me.